# In Ren'Py, how do I show a different image depending on variables?

Tags: sprites, python, scripting, visual-novel, renpy

At the start of my [RenPy](http://www.renpy.org) game, the player chooses a male or female character.  The game plays out the same for both, save for some details.

The problem is that I want to write:

```
show hero normal
```

and get the image of the correct sex of the character chosen at the start.

I started to write a python function to do this, but it looks wrong because there seems to be enough ATL language to do this, even if I can't find a way.

Any idea?

Answer (score 5):

ATL doesn't have an if statement at the moment. You can use DynamicDisplayable
for this - the code looks like:

```
image hero normal = ConditionSwitch(
    "male", "male_normal.png",
    "True", "female_normal.png")
```

I've added an ATL if statement to the list of things I'll add to Ren'Py in the future, since it really should be there.

Comment: I did see this solution on the wiki and tried to use it but it didn't work and I was in a hurry, so I did use the less flexible but instantly working choice ATL block statement instead.

Comment: Any updates on this answer? oris this still the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Someone on this forum showed me that I could use choice in ATL :

```
image hero normal:
    choice( hero_sex == "man" ):
        "hero_man_normal.png"
    choice( hero_sex == "woman" ):
        "hero_woman_normal.png"
```

Not perfect solution but simple enough to solve my problem.